# MongoDB aggregate query - How to make array of array list in to single array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a document like this:
this is my example data is attached below,

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6218b836405919280c209f7e"),
        "projectId": ObjectId("6218a31f405919280c209e18"),
        "accountId": ObjectId("621888e852bd8836c04b8f82"),
        "personalIdRoot": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6221e7514195b43f24c9953f"),
                "personalId": ObjectId("6218b48c405919280c209f6c"),
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6221e7514195b43f24c99540"),
                "personalId": ObjectId("621ef1e40bd3a220f487cd96"),
            }
        ],
        "personalIdFill": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6221e7514195b43f24c9953d"),
                "personalId": ObjectId("6218b48c405919280c209f6c"),
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6221e7514195b43f24c9953e"),
                "personalId": ObjectId("621ef1e40bd3a220f487cd96"),
            }
        ],
        "personalIdCap": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6221e7514195b43f24c9953b"),
                "personalId": ObjectId("6218b48c405919280c209f6c"),
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6221e7514195b43f24c9953c"),
                "personalId": ObjectId("621ef1e40bd3a220f487cd96"),
            }
        ],
        "aps": ObjectId("6218bc18405919280c209f8e"),
    }
]
```

i used this example data for my aggregate query.
my aggregate query is attached below:
please find below code:

```
db.getCollection('funds').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            accountId: ObjectId("621888e852bd8836c04b8f82"),
            projectId: ObjectId("6218a31f405919280c209e18"),
            aps: {
                $in: [
                    ObjectId("6218bc18405919280c209f8e")
                ]
            }

        }
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            "results": [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: 0,
                        values: { "$addToSet": "$personalIdRoot.welderId" },
                        values: { "$addToSet": "$personalIdFill.welderId" },
                        values: { "$addToSet": "$personalIdCap.welderId" }
                    }
                },
            ],
        }
    }
])

my result: 

/* 1 */
{
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0.0,
            "values" : [ 
                [ 
                    ObjectId("6218b48c405919280c209f6c")
                ], 
                [ 
                    ObjectId("6218b2e4405919280c209f68")
                ], 
                [ 
                    ObjectId("6218b48c405919280c209f6c"), 
                    ObjectId("621ef1e40bd3a220f487cd96")
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But i need my result in a single query:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0.0,
            "values" : [ 
                    ObjectId("6218b48c405919280c209f6c"),
                    ObjectId("621ef1e40bd3a220f487cd96")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a result of array of array collections.
but i need it in a single array. like above result

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      accountId: ObjectId("621888e852bd8836c04b8f82"),
      projectId: ObjectId("6218a31f405919280c209e18"),
      aps: {
        $in: [
          ObjectId("6218bc18405919280c209f8e")
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      values: {
        $setUnion: [
          "$personalIdCap.personalId",
          "$personalIdFill.personalId",
          "$personalIdRoot.personalId"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b5kyDSv9DAh)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need every id in a single array with unioque values. But your code shows in seperate ids

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your data does not match your expected result. Please update your question. There is no `ObjectId("6218b2e4405919280c209f68")` in your sample data

Comment: okay i edit the result . I dont need this ObjectId